# What is the difference between Image.onabort and Image.onerror?

Tags: javascript, image, dom-events

I understand that `Image.onabort` or `Image.onerror` fires if image was not loaded successfully. But when is fired which? Can they fire both in some circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abort generally comes from a user action.  For example if image A hasn't finished loading, but the user hits a JavaScript button that switches the "src" to image B.  Then image A would get an "abort" event. I think if you hit the stop button it would trigger the "abort" event as well.  Error events would come from a bad file or something like that that prevents the file from loading.

I would guess that it's possible for them both to fire, but I would also guess that it would be rare.

Comment: So far I have tested, if the image url is incorrect, all browsers fire onerror very quickly. Now I have a script that fails unhandled if both events would be fired. Since both onerror and onabort are called asynchronously, the handling would be quite a problem. If only both calls could not happen... but I am not sure and google gave me no answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know that dealing with asynchronous behavior can be tricky.  I've found the YUI3 AsyncQueue module to be a help -- but even with that it can still be a brain twister.